# extract image name from url using python

Tags: python, url, hyperlink, filenames

i want to extract image name from Links Like this 2 Links

```
url1 = 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/warframe/images/1/17/AshNewLook.png/revision/latest?cb=20141124022921'
url2 = 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/warframe/images/b/b5/BaruukIcon272.png/revision/latest?cb=20181219151057'
```

i tried using os.path.basename but it doesn't work

all i want to extract is image name from Links

'AshNewLook.png' from Page 1

'BaruukIcon272.png' from Page 2

Note: Links Works Without the last part

example:

`url1 = 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/warframe/images/1/17/AshNewLook.png/revision/latest?cb=20141124022921'`
`url2 = 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/warframe/images/1/17/AshNewLook.png'`

url1 will open same page as url2

Comment: Please show us what you tried, and explain why and how it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing would probably be to just split the url by the `/` character and take the third element from the end:

```
pic = url1.split('/')[-3]
```